# Why doesn't is_page(id) work in functions.php?

Tags: functions, loop

When is code in functions.php executed? Is it during the loop? The following does not work when placed in functions.php (not within a function) :

```
if (is_page( 27 )) {

echo 'this is the apply page';

}
```

The codex specifies that [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page#Notes) cannot run within the loop.

Answer (score 4):

`is_page()` relies on a complete global `$wp_query` object. If you call it before the action `template_redirect` has been fired, it might be impossible to get that data.

Wait for a proper action.

Example:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    if ( is_page( 27 ) )
        echo 'this is the apply page';

    return $template;
});
```

You can call `is_page()` in a loop too.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean 'template_redirect' instead of 'template_include' as the first argument to add_action? If you can call is_page() in *the* loop why does the codex say you can't? Just out of date? If so, is there a better reference?

Comment: @codecowboy You can use both hooks or any other hook later. The codex is full of questionable information. The only reliable source is the WordPress code.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to call page ID via **get_the_ID();** function, then you can use is_page function like this:

```
    $id = get_the_ID();

    if ( is_page( $id == 2591 ) )
    {
    return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    else
    {
    return __( 'BUY NOW', 'woocommerce' );
    }
```